# Do i need a transit visa for Paris if i have a Schengen visa issued by Portugal?

Tags: schengen, transit, paris, tours

I am a Indian citizen going to Portugal from India with a Schengen visa issued by Portugal. I am travelling on the sponsorship of my friend in Portugal and have to change flight at Paris with a layover time of 13 hours. Do i need any transit visa for the Paris transit city tour at CDG airport? Also i want to take another tour of Paris while returning to India from Portugal. I will be having a layover time of 13 hours at Paris while returning also.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need and in fact couldn't use an airport transit visa. You will simply enter the Schengen area in Paris (on the way to Portugal) and leave it again in Paris. Once you are through the passport check in Paris, there is nothing preventing you from leaving the airport and going to the city, as far as visa regulations are concerned (you do need to have a boarding pass to reenter the sterile area of the airport when catching your flight to Portugal).